# First and Last element of String in brackets when copied to file

Tags: python, list, tkinter, clipboard

##### Explaination:

I have a function `text()`, which is to append a series of strings to the list `Prüftext`, depending on if a variable is `0` or `1`, and copy that string into my clipboard.

I get the strings which are to be appended from two lists, that are defined outside of the function.
These are:

```py
SetBlock = ["SetBlock1","SetBlock2","SetBlock3","SetBlock4"]
```

and:

```py
TextBlock = ["TextBlock1","TextBlock2","TextBlock3","TextBlock4"]
```

---

##### My Problem:

When I copy the string into a file, the first and last elements are in curly brackets like this:

```
{SetBlock1} TextBlock1 TextBlock2 {SetBlock3}
```

Or when I switch out the lists in the function I get this:

```
TextBlock1 {SetBlock1} {SetBlock3} TextBlock2
```

But I want:

```
SetBlock1 TextBlock1 TextBlock2 SetBlock3
```

If I append a string after "manually" by doing `Prüftext.append("manual string")`, it is also in curly brackets.

So it seems to be related in some kind to the lists and how they are accessed?

I have imported `tkinter` as `Tk`

---

##### The function:

```
def text(pfVar):
    Prüftext = []
    dummy = ""

    if pfVar == 0:
        Prüftext.append(SetBlock[0])

    if pfVar == 1:
        Prüftext.append(SetBlock[1])

    for i in range(0, len(Indicator)):
        if Indicator[i] == 1:
            Prüftext.append(TextBlock[i])

    if kosten == -1:
        Prüftext.append(SetBlock[3])

    if kosten == 1:
        Prüftext.append(SetBlock[2])

    if kosten == 0:
        dummy = dummy

    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(Prüftext)
    r.update()
    r.destroy()

    print(Prüftext)
```

I have looked at the `tkinter` documentation and tried to change out the text in the lists `SetBlock`, and `TextBlock` but didn't find anything that I think would help me.

Comment: Do you have a line like `Prüftext = r.clipboard_get()` elsewhere before calling `print(Prüftext)`? BTW, try to change `r.clipboard_append(Prüftext)` to `r.clipboard_append(", ".join(Prüftext))`.

Comment: Hello acw1668,
your suggestion to change `r.clipboard_append(Prüftext)` to
`r.clipboard_append(", ".join(Prüftext))` worked perfectly!

I did not have a line `Prüftext = r.clipboard_get()` before `print(Prüftext)`.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `r.clipboard_append(Prüftext)` to `r.clipboard_append(", ".join(Prüftext))`